# Golang Client for Bitfinex API V2.0: How to Post Authenticated Requests

Tags: rest, authentication, go

I'm trying to use the Bitfinex REST API V2.0 and [here](https://bitfinex.readme.io/v2/docs/rest-auth) there is a description of how a request should be authenticated. Here below is my `golang` implementation:

```
func (c *Client) newAuthenticatedRequest(method string, refURL string, data map[string]interface{}) (*http.Request, error) {
    path := "auth/r/" + refURL
    rel, err := url.Parse(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    payload := "{}"
    if data != nil {
        p, err := json.Marshal(data)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        payload = string(p)
    }

    url := c.BaseURL.ResolveReference(rel)
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url.String(), strings.NewReader(payload))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    nonce := utils.GetNonce()
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("bfx-nonce", nonce)
    req.Header.Add("bfx-apikey", c.APIKey)
    req.Header.Add("bfx-signature", c.signPayload("/api/v2/" + path + nonce + payload))

    return req, nil
}

func (c *Client) signPayload(payload string) string {
    sig := hmac.New(sha512.New384, []byte(c.APISecret))
    sig.Write([]byte(payload))
    return hex.EncodeToString(sig.Sum(nil))
}

func (c *Client) do(req *http.Request, v interface{}) (*Response, error) {
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    response, err := newResponse(resp)
    if err != nil {
       return nil, err
    }

    if v != nil {
        err = json.Unmarshal(response.Body, v)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    return response, nil
}

func (s *WalletsService) All() ([]Wallet, error) {
    req, err := s.client.newAuthenticatedRequest("POST", "wallets", nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var w []Wallet
    _, err = s.client.do(req, &w)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return w, nil
}
```

The problem is that when i `POST` a request, I always get back error `[10100] apikey: invalid`. Is it correct to set the payload to `{}` when empty? I've tried any possible combination but no way.

Comment: I don't think the payload matters at all (and can probably be empty). It looks like you might be signing against the value of `"/api/v2/" + path`, but requesting a slightly different path. You should probably sign against `/api` + the actual request path anyway to avoid this possible bug, and print them out to make sure you're signing the path you think you are.

Comment: Just printed them out... the request url is `https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/auth/r/wallets` and I'm signing against `/api/v2/auth/r/wallets` + `nonce` + `paylaod` (if any) as described in their documentation.

Comment: Is the signature string returned by your `signPayload` function lower-case? This was the resolution in my case.